# Maximise a webview in the android window

Tags: java, android, webview, fullscreen

I am new to android development but after searching for a while i can not get a solution to maximise my webview in my android window (12080*800 in my current test). Same problem appear on the physical device (a samsung 10.1)

https://dl.dropbox.com/s/d57nmlhbs8pu6k7/2013-06-11%20at%2010.18.15.png

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

//Remove title bar
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

//Remove notification bar and set fullscreen
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

// add the webview
WebView www = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
www.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
www.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
www.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
www.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);
www.getSettings().setSaveFormData(false);
www.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

// load html
www.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.8:3000/app/tgg4yme");
```

}

I have tried to fill the window through the editor too... no success

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure it's not a problem with the HTML of your site? What happens if you load a different URL, eg http://google.com?

Comment: same problem with google. It looks like i can't use a part of the screen...

Comment: Try removing `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"`  from your WebView xml

Comment: I just tried this exact code and it works, is full screen. I don't think it's a code issue. How does your site look if you look at it in the native browser on the emulator/device? Do you have any weird proxies, etc. happening to your net connection?

Comment: No weird proxies. This is an test example of an app :http://www.duck.li/app/tgg4yme

Comment: I got it working full screen using Phonegap. Thanks a lot for your answers :-)